# Is it possible to implement singleton across two different jvm?

Tags: java

Im wondering if anyone there is convinient way how to implement singleton accross two different java virtual machines. We are using JMS to comunicate between these two. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't think about singletons, think about a service. You can establish a service on one JVM and communicate with it via JMS from the other machine.

Comment: +1: You can have one service with one singleton which is available to either JVM, either in its own JVM or in one of the existing JVMs.

Comment: @Peter: That's what I meant. I was suggesting that singletons are not an issue here.

Answer (score 3):

Everything is possible, but is it worth it? Most likely there is another approach to solve your problem. If you wish to communicate between application using singleton-like object, try JMS, web-services, RMI, shared file, *anything*...

But if you really wanna hurt yourself: http://www.terracotta.org.

Answer (score 2):

[EJB 3.1 supports singleton EJB](http://blogs.oracle.com/MaheshKannan/entry/singleton_ejb_support_in_glassfish)'s. I think this is the best way where you can centrally deploy this.